# How to implement iterator for a LinkedList using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am implementing LinkedList in Kotlin. I wanted to implement `Iterator` interface so that I can for each on the LinkedList like so `linkedlist.forEach{}`.

here is the code that I have

```kotlin
class SinglyLinkedList<T> : Iterator<T> {

    var head: SinglyLinkedListNode<T>? = null
        private set(value) {
            cursor = value
            field = value
        }

    var count = 0
        private set

    // This is needed for iterator functionality.
    private var cursor: SinglyLinkedListNode<T>? = null

 override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        // the problem is when I return in the middle of the loop
        // then start new for each
        // cursor is not equal head
        return if (cursor == null){
           // if this is the last time, reset cursor so that next time we start from the begining
            cursor = head
            false
        } else {
            true
        }
    }
    override fun next(): T {
        val temp = cursor
        cursor = cursor!!.next
        return temp!!.value
    }
}
```

the issue happens when I do something like this

```kotlin
linkedlist.forEach{
 if(it) == 1 return
}
```

then I try to `forEach` again, it will continue from the last element it stopped at.

Comment: You seem to have confused `Iterator` with `Iterable`. Your list should be **`Iterable`**. That means it should provide an `iterator()` **method** that returns an `Iterator`. It should not implement `Iterator` itself.

Comment: you're right! I wanted something that has a state of its own. and I didn't know exactly what was the difference between `Iterable` and `Iterator`. thanks for clearing that up. @Fureeish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> then I try to `forEach` again, it will continue from the last element it stopped at.

Yes, that is what an `Iterator` is supposed to do. An `Iterator` is a stateful thing - it knows which element it is currently "at". Do you want your linked list to know which element it is currently "at"? You probably don't, do you? You want your linked list, and the *iterator* of that linked list, to be different things.

The list can be itera*ble*, meaning that you can get an `iterator` from the list.

```
class SinglyLinkedList<T> : Iterable<T> {

    var head: SinglyLinkedListNode<T>? = null
        private set

    var count = 0
        private set

    override fun iterator() = object: Iterator<T> {
        private var cursor: SinglyLinkedListNode<T>? = head

        override fun hasNext() = cursor != null

        override fun next() = (cursor?.value ?: throw NoSuchElementException()).also {
            cursor = cursor?.next
        }
    }
}
```

Now doing `forEach` on the list will create an iterator of the list, and after iterating through the list (no matter which element you have iterated to), the iterator will be discarded. The next time you call `forEach`, a brand new iterator gets created.

Comment: you're right. this was the missing part for me. my linkedlist didn't know which element it was at, and I had to do workarounds to fix most of the cases.
your answer works perfectly. thanks.